# Como desativar a validação de senha mysql com ZoneMinder: ERROR 1819 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, password

Carreguei o plugin de validação de senha no MySQL 5.7 no Ubuntu Server 16.04 para deixar o sistema com mais proteção, mas parece que este plugin força todas as senhas a cumprir determinadas regras e acaba que nenhuma está correta, dando esse erro:

```
error 1819 (hy000) your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solução:**

Digite no terminal do Linux (Ubuntu), em seguida insira a senha do Root(administrador) do linux:

```
sudo mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

Ele irá entrar dentro do Mysql, veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, dentro do mysql digite:

```
uninstall plugin validate_password;
```

Retornará a seguinte mensagem: *Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)*

Pronto!

Plugin desabilitado.